# Clock warning when using MDRectangleFlatButton and MDRaisedButton

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am making a desktop application using **kivy & kivymd** and when creating the settings screen for the app I used two **MDRectangleFlatButon and MDRaisedButtons** but to make them scalable, I gave both of them a **size_hint_x of .5** for each to take up half of the screen. However, as soon as the program starts I get this warning from kivy:

```
[CRITICAL] [Clock       ] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute
```

the interesting part is that if I switch the current screen to the one that I defined them inside of it, the warning stops. Why am I getting this warning and how can I stop it? My python file:

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '850')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '530')
Config.set('graphics', 'minimum_width', '850')
Config.set('graphics', 'minimum_height', '530')
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class SettingsTab(MDCard, MDTabsBase):
    pass

class Example(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_file("design.kv")

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Teal"
        return self.kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example().run()
```

My kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
<SettingsTab>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: .95, .95
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    border_radius: 5
    radius: [5]
    elevation: 20
BoxLayout:
    MDNavigationRail:
        color_active: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        MDNavigationRailItem:
            icon: "list-status"
            on_release:
                screens.current = "downloads_screen"
        MDNavigationRailItem:
            icon: "cog"
            on_release:
                screens.current = "settings"
        MDNavigationRailItem:
            icon: "information"
            on_release:
                screens.current = "activity_log"

    ScreenManager:
        id: screens
        Screen:
            name: "downloads_screen"
        Screen:
            name: "activity_log"
        Screen:
            name: "settings"
            MDTabs:
                SettingsTab:
                    title: "DOWNLOAD"
                SettingsTab:
                    title: "COLOR"
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        adaptive_height: True
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        padding: 10
                        MDLabel:
                            text: "Theme Manager: "
                            font_style: "H5"
                            padding_y: 10
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.texture_size[1]
                        MDBoxLayout:
                            adaptive_height: True
                            spacing: 10
                            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                                text: "See Current Palette"
                                size_hint_x: .5
                            MDRaisedButton:
                                text: "Open Theme Picker"
                                size_hint_x: .5
                SettingsTab:
                    title: "INFO"
```

**EDIT:** Just to mention, I do not just want the warning go away, I want to stop the performance drop. Even if I didn't add **size_hint** to any of the buttons (which doesn't cause the error anymore), the app becomes very sluggish and slow. When resizing the program there is a huge delay and when the program starts it is really doing a number on my cpu and it won't change until I switch to that frame.

Comment: No idea why that is happening, but if you put your "settings" `Screen` as the first listed under `ScreenManager` in your `kv`, then it goes away.

Comment: @JohnAnderson the problem is that I don't want the settings screen to be the first one that is shown

Comment: @JohnAnderson I updated the question to make my intention clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the order of your `Screens` definition, so that the "settings" `Screen` is the first listed  under `ScreenManager` in your `kv`, then the error messages go away. Then adding to the `Example` class definition:

```
def on_start(self):
    self.kv.ids.screens.transition = NoTransition()
    self.kv.ids.screens.current = 'downloads_screen'
    self.kv.ids.screens.transition = SlideTransition()
```

makes the `downloads_screen` appear first.

Comment: As of now, this seems to suffice. Thank you.